# apache doesn't show files which have different owner

Tags: linux, centos, apache-2.4

I have created a domain in WHM for user `alex`. now if I put any file in `public_html` folder of this domain which has the owner defined as `root`, apache does not allow visiting of the file in browser, it says `not found`. but if I change the owner of file to `alex`, everything works fine!

now I want apache to allow visiting every file in public_html, even if the owner is root and not alex. how to do that?

Comment: apache user www-data or whichever  your httpd server is using should have the least amounf of access possible to files and directories. For directories Apache should access to present the data, they should have at least x permission (search) and for files, r permission at most. In cases like public_html like I said in another cooment, root:root 755 for directories and 644 for  files should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Apache run under www-data user. This user have certain privileges, but not enought to read root's files.

A solution is to add `www-data` group to files : `chgrp www-data /path/to/files` ; then adjust permission of files to allow group members to read these files : `chmod g+r /path/to/files`

An other solution, not really recommanded, is to allow `other` to read files : `chmod o+r /path/to/files`

Answer (score 1):

> now I want apache to allow visiting every file in public_html, even if the owner is root and not alex. how to do that?

Short answer: You can't.
Slightly longer answer: You shouldn't.

*Learn* about Linux File System permissions and how to work *with* them.
Trying to "force" your way *around* them will only give you trouble, later on.

I'd *suggest* that you:

- Create a Group that contains the account running Apache and the one delivering the files,
- Change the owning Group of the target directory to that Group,
- Set the [SetGID bit](https://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/22/linux-permissions-demystified/) on that directory.

Comment: this is a terrible advice, precisely Apache processes should never have ownership of any kind to static files it serves if it can be avoided. root:root and permissions 755 for dirs and 644 for files would be just fine.